# Making only hyperlink text appear rather than entire link URL

Tags: php, html

For the link below, I would like $link1 to appear at the bottom as the anchor text "Comment Link" as a hyperlink.  Instead, the entire link is showing down at the bottom.

How could I make it so only "Comment Link" is showing?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$link1 = "<a href='http://www.domain.com/path/comments/index.php?submission=".urlencode($submission)."&submissionid=".urlencode($submissionid)."&url=".urlencode($url)."&countcomments=".urlencode($countcomments)."&submittor=".urlencode($submittor)."&submissiondate=".urlencode($submissiondate)."&dispurl=".urlencode($dispurl).">Comment Link</a>";

    $message1 = "
Someone made the following comment on your submission $submission:

$comment


Please click the link below to see the comment in context.

$link1


";
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing closing ' at the end of your anchor's `href` attribute.

Comment: It's not a comment on the code he put up. It's the reason he is seeing the full URL. Firefox etc fix up the HTML, IE doesn't.

Comment: I neither think it should be a comment. He clearly gives the solution to the problem.